# obtener la suma maxima de un subvector

Tags: java

Tengo este algoritmo resuelto por el metodo de divide y venceras que lo que hace es obtener la suma maxima de un subvector, pero me sale una complejidad O(nlogn) y tengo que resolverlo para que sea complejidad O(n).

### Intentos

Lo que he intentado ha sido hacer que la llamada del subvector izquierdo devuelva ya el máximo de la parte izquierda y lo mismo con la parte derecha para ahorrarnos una llamada. Por último el resultado sería la concatenación de las 3 sumas.

### Ejemplo

Un ejemplo es dado el array

```
{–2, 11, –4, 13, –5, 2}
```

> la suma es 20.

```
{1, -3, 4, -2, -1, 6}
```

> la suma es 7.

```
{4, -3, 5, -2, -1, 2, 6, -2}
```

> la suma es 11.

### Código

```
public static int sumaMaxDyV(int a[], int izq, int der)
    {
        if (der == izq) {  //si el array contiene 0 o 1 elemento
            return a[izq];
        }
 
        int medio = (izq + der) / 2;  //encuentra el elemento del medio del array
 
        // Encuentra la suma máxima de subarray para el subarray izquierdo,
        // incluyendo el elemento del medio
        int izqMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = medio; i >= izq; i--)
        {
            suma += a[i];
            if (suma > izqMax) {
                izqMax = suma;
            }
        }
 
        // Encuentra la suma máxima de subarray para el subarray derecho,
        // excluyendo el elemento del medio
        int derMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        suma = 0;    // restablece la suma a 0
        for (int i = medio + 1; i <= der; i++)
        {
            suma += a[i];
            if (suma > derMax) {
                derMax = suma;
            }
        }
 
        // Encuentra recursivamentemente la suma máxima de subarray para la izquierda
        // y subarray derecho, y toma el máximo
        int maxIzqDer = Integer.max(sumaMaxDyV(a, izq, medio),
                                    sumaMaxDyV(a, medio + 1, der));
 
        // devuelve el máximo de los tres
        return Integer.max(maxIzqDer, izqMax + derMax);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un ejemplo de uso? ¿Debe ser por recursión?

Comment: La cosa es obtener una complejidad O(n), da igual si por recursividad o no, el proposito es que de un array, haga la suma de los subvectores y vaya obteniendo el mayor.

Comment: "Divide y vencerás" es solo un concepto que trata de descomponer una tarea grande en tareas más pequeñas y fáciles de realizar, no es un algoritmo.

Comment: Define "suma máxima". No me queda claro viendo los ejemplos que das.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no demuestra investigación. Una búsqueda muestra que es un [problema conocido](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) y lo que realidad quiere es el algoritmo de Kadane. Pero la pregunta en sí no habla de dicho algoritmo, solo pretende encontrar una solución de menor complejidad al problema.

Comment: [Aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/java-maximum-subarray) puedes encontrar una primera solución al problema y el algoritmo de Kadane también. Claro que en Java. Tampoco aclaras si la complejidad es en base al tiempo o qué.

Comment: @Mateo, estamos de acuerdo en que la pregunta no es del todo clara, yo no la he entendido, hasta que no seguí el enlace que pusiste, ahora bien, esto nos deja claro dos cosas: A) eres más despierto que yo, B) la pregunta no era del todo inentendible, además, no conocer el algoritmo de Kadane, no es razón de cierre (de hecho, preguntar implica desconocimiento), por otro lado, no habiendo respuestas similares en SOes, tampoco se puede cerrar por duplicada, creo que lo ideal, es que elabores una respuesta, para que quede asentada en el sitio, y no depender de enlaces... es mi opinión.

Comment: @Marce no me refiero al algoritmo en sí, sino al problema. Lo que importa es que deberían investigar antes de preguntar. Antes de poder responder la pregunta debería ser mejorada. Puede que incluso deba cambiar toda la pregunta a *¿Qué es el algoritmo de Kadane?*, cómo funciona u otra.

Comment: @Mateo Preguntar es investigar, tu conoces la respuesta, así es fácil encontrarla, para el que no la conoce... es casi imposible.

Comment: @Marce lo dice la [ayuda](/help/privileges/create-posts). Segundo párrafo

Comment: @"**hayas buscado una solución, y puedas compartir los resultados de tu investigación con nosotros**", buscar solución != busca en google, "** compartir los resultados de tu investigación**" == mostra lo que intentaste... **al menos asi lo veo yo**!!! jajaj (seguro te suena).

Comment: @Marce mí opinión es cerrarla. Confío en la inteligencia colectiva. Si realmente debería ser cerrada, será cerrada.